# Histograms and/or bar graphs split by group level

Tags: r, ggplot2

| home | season | avg_days | n_season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anadolu Efes | 2013-2014 | 14 days | 6 |
| Anadolu Efes | 2014-2015 | 14 days | 6 |
| Anadolu Efes | 2015-2016 | 14 days | 6 |
| Anadolu Efes | 2016-2017 | 10 days | 6 |
| Anadolu Efes | 2017-2018 | 11 days | 6 |
| Anadolu Efes | 2018-2019 | 11 days | 6 |
| Barcelona | 2013-2014 | 15 days | 6 |
| Barcelona | 2014-2015 | 14 days | 6 |
| Barcelona | 2015-2016 | 13 days | 6 |
| Barcelona | 2016-2017 | 11 days | 6 |
| Barcelona | 2017-2018 | 12 days | 6 |
| Barcelona | 2018-2019 | 11 days | 6 |

Hello,

I have a data frame like the one reported above and I would like to create a graph (histogram or graph bar) with ggplot2 that shows the trend of the avg_days for each team (6 teams) going on with the seasons. The difficulties I face are mainly two: create a single graph for each team and plot two discrete variables (season on the x-axis and avg_days on the y-axis).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the poor layout.

Answer (score 1):

To plot `avg_days` by `season` keep the digits in `avg_days` with a regex, coerce to integer, then pipe to `ggplot`. The posted data set only has two teams so I facet with `facet_wrap`. Another option is [`facet_grid`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

```r
x <- "home  season  avg_days    n_season
'Anadolu Efes'  2013-2014   '14 days'   6
'Anadolu Efes'  2014-2015   '14 days'   6
'Anadolu Efes'  2015-2016   '14 days'   6
'Anadolu Efes'  2016-2017   '10 days'   6
'Anadolu Efes'  2017-2018   '11 days'   6
'Anadolu Efes'  2018-2019   '11 days'   6
Barcelona   2013-2014   '15 days'   6
Barcelona   2014-2015   '14 days'   6
Barcelona   2015-2016   '13 days'   6
Barcelona   2016-2017   '11 days'   6
Barcelona   2017-2018   '12 days'   6
Barcelona   2018-2019   '11 days'   6
"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df1 %>%
  mutate(avg_days = sub("(^\\d+).*$", "\\1", avg_days),
         avg_days = as.integer(avg_days)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(season, avg_days)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ home) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>